# how to show sub-menu when using the scroll bar on a menu?

Tags: html, css, submenu

Good morning, I have a menu where you need it has a vertical side bar. As you can see in the picture, I could add it. However, when the mouse pointer hovers over the menu items, submenus appear, but they are hidden by the bar. I would like the sub menus stay overlapped the bar, ie, they appeared in front, not getting hidden. Already tried changing the z-index of the submenu, but it did not work. Anyone know any alternative, or how can I solve this?

[image]

then, as the system menu is all dynamically mounted, I created an example in jsFiddle. The problem is that the menu has sub-menus, and when I try to access them, they are "inside" the box that creates the scrollbar. link: jsfiddle.net/tBJe3/10/

thank you!

Comment: do u need that scorll bar

Comment: I need, because the menu where I use the scroll bar, has many options.

Comment: Can you post the html/css you're using right now with a JSFiddle? It's hard to help figure out what's wrong looking at a screenshot.

Comment: Of course, you can see an example in http://jsfiddle.net/tBJe3/10/

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
.menuLateral {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 35%;
    height:200px;
    color: #B2C2B9;
    float: left;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tBJe3/11/

Comment: I'll use the menu where it is created dynamically. may have for example 100 menu options. So I need the scroll.
That way you posted if I have more menu options, it does not show these options.

Comment: if u use scroll means the submenu also showing in scroll if u wat to view u need to scroll for viewing that if u move the cursor the submenu will disappear...

Comment: yes, I need it to have some type of scroll bar, to be able to limit the size of the div, without limiting the number of menu items, and he must let the sub menu can get out of this rectangle that creates scrool.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have set `position: relative;` for almost all containers. If you remove them, your `absolutely positioned` sub-menus will be relative to the document and also will be on top of your `scrollable` content.

Here is the updated version of your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBJe3/15/).

**Please note**, that by doing in this way, some of your `sub-menu`s will not appear where you want. So maybe you need to make with fixed positions or position them *manually* (and *dynamically*) using `JavaScript`.